# Best method of text truncating

Tags: templating, richtext

I see that there are [Trimmer](https://github.com/rkingon/Craft-Plugin--Trimmer) and [Truncate](https://github.com/nizur/truncate/) out there that have been created for truncating text but I don't believe either does what it is I'm looking for.

I'd like to truncate text similar to how [Hacksaw](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/hacksaw) for ExpressionEngine works. Allowing me to allow or disallow html tags, and making sure that even if it cuts off before a tag is closed, that it automatically properly closes the tag. I wouldn't want to turn the entire lower half of my page into a hyperlink for instance if i happen to truncate mid-link. I do want to maintain the ability for links to be in the text that is being truncated, and multiple paragraphs, etc. however.

Any tips would be fantastic.

Comment: [Hacksaw](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/hacksaw) has an open source license (MIT), so you could make a Craft version of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to allow or disallow specific tags, you can use wordsmith plugin and its [chop](https://wordsmith.docs.topshelfcraft.com/guide/truncation.html#chop) filter.

But if you don't need such advanced functionality, you can just use Twig macros.

In article [Truncating text with Twig macros in Craft CMS](http://craftsnippets.com/articles/truncating-text-with-twig-macros-in-craft-cms?s=s)
 on my blog I describe two macros - one that truncates by **number of words** and one that truncates by **number of characters** - while ensuring that truncated string does not have split words.

Comment: In 2022 this is a better solution, marked it as the new correct answer given it references Wordsmith as well as alternate methods.

Answer (score 18):

https://github.com/ryanshrum/hacksaw

This hasn't been fully tested for production, or documented for that matter, but I have migrated it over and tested **basic** usage as per the docs on devot-ee. It should, at the very least, give you a nice start.

You can use the Twig filter with: `{{ entry.fieldHandle|hacksaw(words="100") }}`

Comment: Rock on Ryan, thanks for porting it over. Get it up on http://straightupcraft.com/ when you get a chance. This does exactly what i need (as far as my current needs), haven't tested it extensively.

Comment: After posting it originally, I went back and modified a few things after testing it a bit more thoroughly. I noticed one of the downfalls was as you said leaving HTML elements unclosed so I added in a new method to take care of that. I believe it now to function as the EE version does. I will work at getting it up on Straight up Craft as well as getting it fully documented here in the next couple days. Glad to help.

Comment: Nice! tnx for sharing.

Comment: We see an issue with current version of Hacksaw where the content contains non-breaking spaces. They're being converted into little black diamonds with questions marks in them. Redactor loves to add non-breaking spaces, in my experience.

Comment: There's also another issue that it's not working currently well with text in Cyrillic (or maybe any Unicode enabled range of characters).

Comment: I installed it and all I see now is `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in F:\xampp\htdocs\craft\plugins\hacksaw\twigextensions\HacksawTwigExtension.php on line 32` and I can't even get back to uninstalling the plugin.

Answer (score 13):

Doesn't answer the specific question but based on the title in search results it might be helpful for anyone just wanting to truncate a string:

```
{{ entry.title | length > 75 ? entry.title | slice(0, 75) ~ '...' : entry.title }}
```

Also doesn't require a plugin. Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13143001/symfony-2-twig-limit-the-length-of-the-text-and-put-three-dots).

Answer (score 2):

[Wordsmith](https://wordsmith.docs.topshelfcraft.com/guide/truncation.html) plugin is very useful in manipulating the text. For example:

```twig
{{ entry.fieldHandle|chop(limit=100, unit='c', append=' ...') }}
```